# Read access violation in string destructor

Tags: c++, oracle, exception, occi

How is it possible that string destructor throws an exception?
It's thrown at the end of try block for variable `s`.

```
Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
Connection *con;
con = env->createConnection(Config::login, Config::password, Config::connection_string);


string sqlStmt = "SELECT user FROM dual";
auto stmt = con->createStatement(sqlStmt);
ResultSet *rset = stmt->executeQuery();
try {
    rset->next();
    string s = rset->getString(1);
    cout << "user: " << s << endl;
}  // exception thrown here
```

> read access violation _Pnext was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: this is a null pointer.

Comment: As `s` is `auto` we are left to guess what type it is.  How do you know it's a string and not a pointer to a temporary buffer?

Comment: That naked `rset->next()` is ill-advised. `rset` should be checked before any of that, and more importantly, `if (rset->next()) { ..your code.. }` is the stock modus-operandi to protect you from yourself. Unrelated, this deserves the mysql tag if that's what you're using (I'm assuming it is).

Comment: @RichardCritten For clarity, I've changed the `auto` to `std::string`. Tested and it does the same thing.

Comment: @WhozCraig I've simplified the code for the purpose of asking this question. I check if `rset` is good in production.

Comment: Having the same problem as you, OP. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the different versions CRT library. You application's and Oracle's CRT library version must match.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like a std::string exception.

> That naked rset->next() is ill-advised. rset should be checked before any of that, and more importantly, if (rset->next()) { ..your code.. } is the stock modus-operandi to protect you from yourself.

Just check:

```
if (rset->next() == Status::DATA_AVAILABLE) {
   auto s = rset->getString(1);
}
```